# Intellij code completion of partial class names?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intelij, is there a way to autocomplete partial class names under the following conditions...

1. Start typing "Calendar" without quotes
2. magic-here
3. Intelij suggests "GregorianCalendar"

The key being that if I type any substring I want to see a list of classes that contain that substring, particularly if that substring is uppercased. In many cases the prefix or leading part of the classname isn't what us developers remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've pressed Ctrl+Space and you have a completion list open, you can type `*Calendar` in it and see only the classes that contain `Calendar` somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Just tried that but I can't type *in* the completion list and the Ctrl+Space only seems to bring up the classes that start with Calendar.

Comment: The key is having to hit the ctrl+Space *first*. I was hoping for something a bit smarter.

Comment: Another possibility would be to enter `*Calen` and press Ctrl+Space after that. It's not implemented yet. You can create a feature request though: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard